# gcc:linker input file unused because linking not done

Tags: linux, gcc

When I run a make file in Linux to compile C codes, I get the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -DSOLARIS -DXP_UNIX -DMCC_HTTPD -D_REENTRANT -I/opt/profile/OraAlert_test/code/include -I/usr/netscape/server4/plugins/include -I../../pwutils -I../../database/src  -I../../access/src -I/data/share/capscan/include -o getEnv.o -c ../src/
gcc: ../src/: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

I have tried searching for related questions in stackoverflow and tried the the solutions suggested. Still this could not be resolved. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't `-c` imply we're only compiling and not linking anyway? and why are you passing it a directory rather than a source file?

Answer (score 3):

You have a compilation command without a source file.
What is it supposed to compile?

The error is indeed misleading. It assumes you want to link with `../src/`, but `-c` says no linkage is to be done.